# finding the population in Statistics

Tags: statistics

I have the following question:

Netflix would like to estimate the proportion of their current subscribers who would pay extra for a premium membership including access to more movies and TV shows. To do this they plan to calculate a 95% confidence interval to estimate the proportion. They would like a margin of error of 0.05. How many subscribers must they sample to obtain this interval?

I know the answer is 385 but I keep getting an answer of 36.8 when I use this formula: n = ((z*/m)^2)*p*(1-p*) and it doesn't work when I use this formula either: n = ((z* * sigma)/m)^2.
Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: provide us with all the given information about the exercise

Comment: @ombk this is all the information that was provided for the question

Comment: what is p? $m=0.05$ ok $z=1.96$

Comment: this is all the information they gave me, so that is why I am stuck on it. Is there a way to find p?

Comment: how do you know that the answer is 385?

Comment: They gave me an answer sheet with the final answers but not the method

Answer (score 1):

For a Wald-type confidence interval for a population proportion $p$, the confidence limits are $$\hat p - z_{\alpha/2}^* \sqrt{\frac{\hat p (1- \hat p)}{n}}, \quad  \hat p +  z_{\alpha/2}^* \sqrt{\frac{\hat p (1- \hat p)}{n}}$$ where $\hat p$ is the sample proportion observed, $n$ is the sample size, and $z_{\alpha/2}^*$ is the upper $\alpha/2$ quantile of the standard normal distribution for a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval.  If a $95\%$ CI is desired, this corresponds to $\alpha = 0.05$, hence $$z_{\alpha/2}^* \approx 1.96.$$  The quantity $$ME = z_{\alpha/2}^* \sqrt{\frac{\hat p (1 - \hat p)}{n}}$$ is known as the *margin of error*.  Since we also desire $ME \le 0.05$, we solve for $n$ to obtain $$n \ge \hat p (1 - \hat p) \left(\frac{z_{\alpha/2}^*}{ME}\right)^2.$$  The only unknown quantity is $\hat p$; but since $\hat p(1 - \hat p) \le 1/4$ for all $\hat p \in [0,1]$ (see note below), we know that a sample size of at least $$n \ge \left(\frac{z_{\alpha/2}^*}{2ME}\right)^2$$ guarantees the Wald interval will have a margin of error less than the desired margin no matter the sample proportion observed.  Substituting the given values results in $$n \ge \left(\frac{1.96}{2(0.05)}\right)^2 = 384.16,$$ for which we must round up to guarantee the sample size is sufficient, hence $n = 385$.  But notice that this is a crude bound; if the sample proportion is extreme, then $n$ may be substantially smaller.  Also note that this is based on the Wald interval, which in extreme cases does not have good coverage properties.  But a discussion of this is beyond the scope of the question.

---

Note.

Why is $\hat p (1 - \hat p) \le 1/4$ on $\hat p \in [0,1]$?  This may be shown in many ways; an elementary one is to write $$\hat p (1 - \hat p) = \frac{1}{4} - \left( \frac{1}{4} - \hat p + \hat p^2 \right) = \frac{1}{4} - \left( \hat p - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2.$$  Since the square of a real number is never negative, the RHS is never greater than $1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

You will find your answer here

[image]

[Reference](https://www.checkmarket.com/blog/how-to-estimate-your-population-and-survey-sample-size/)